# How to prevent Jinja2 substitution in Ansible playbook?

Tags: jinja2, ansible, configuration-management

In my playbook, a JSON file is included using the `include_vars` module. The content of the JSON file is as given below:

```
{
  "Component1": {
    "parameter1" : "value1",
    "parameter2" : "value2"
  },

  "Component2": {
    "parameter1" : "{{ NET_SEG_VLAN }}",
    "parameter2": "value2"       
  }
}
```

After the JSON file is included in the playbook, I am using `uri` module to sent an http request as given below:

```
- name: Configure Component2 variables using REST API
  uri:
      url: "http://0.0.0.0:5000/vse/api/v1.0/config/working/Component2/configvars/"
      method: POST
      return_content: yes
      HEADER_x-auth-token: "{{ login_resp.json.token }}"
      HEADER_Content-Type: "application/json"
      body:  "{{ Component2 }}"
      body_format: json
```

As it can be seen, the body of the http request is send with the JSON data `Component2`. However, Jinja2 tries to substitute the `{{ NET_SEG_VLAN }}` in the JSON file and throws and `undefined` error. The intention is not to substitute anything inside the JSON file using Jinja2 and send the body as it is in http request.

How to prevent the Jinja2 substitution for the variables included from the JSON file?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should able to escape the variable even with `{{'{{NET_SEG_VLAN}}'}}` to tell jinja not to template anything inside that block.

Comment: this will work for the 1st jinja , but the second will fail

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to [escape](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#escaping) the variable with `{% raw %}` and `{% endraw %}` to tell Jinja not to template anything inside that block.

Comment: the problem with pure jinja solution: this will work for the 1st templatization, then "{% raw %}" will go away, then second jinja templatization will fail.

Answer (score 4):

**`!unsafe`**

From documentation at https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/user_guide/playbooks_advanced_syntax.html#unsafe-or-raw-strings:

> When handling values returned by lookup plugins, Ansible uses a data type called `unsafe` to block templating. Marking data as unsafe prevents malicious users from abusing Jinja2 templates to execute arbitrary code on target machines. The Ansible implementation ensures that unsafe values are never templated. It is more comprehensive than escaping Jinja2 with `{% raw %} ... {% endraw %}` tags.
>
> You can use the same `unsafe` data type in variables you define, to prevent templating errors and information disclosure. You can mark values supplied by [vars_prompts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/user_guide/playbooks_prompts.html#unsafe-prompts) as `unsafe`. You can also use unsafe in playbooks. The most common use cases include passwords that allow special characters like `{` or `%`, and JSON arguments that look like templates but should not be templated.

I am using it all the time, like this:

```yaml
# Load JSON content, as a raw string with !unsafe
- tags: ["always"]
  set_fact:
    dashboard_content: !unsafe "{{ lookup('file', './dash.json') | to_json }}"

# Build dictionnary via template
- tags: ["always"]
  set_fact:
    cc: "{{ lookup('template', './templates/cm_dashboard.yaml.j2') | from_yaml }}"

## cm_dashboard.yaml.j2 content:
hello: {{ cc_dashboard_content }}

# Now, "cc" is a dict variable, with "hello" field protected!
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in current versions of Ansible (at least, not when trying to run a  `command` that contains `{{...}}` markers).

Comment: which version exactly please ?

Comment: ansible 2.12.1, run with a task like: `command: !unsafe echo "{{ this should be rendered verbatim }}"`. Other suggestions here (using `{%raw%}` or embedding the text as a Jinja string value) work fine.