# How can I escape double curly braces in jinja2?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I need to escape double curly braces in a code I'm working on using Ansible.
The thing is I have all those parameters that needs to be transformed in variables. Basically I'm working on a template creator.

I've tried using `{% raw %}{{ name-of-variable }}{% endraw %}` but it did not work. When I tried `/{/{ name-of-variable \}\}` I almost got it, but I am trying to get rid of the backslashes too.

Here's a bit of the code:

```
local_action:
    module: replace
    path: "/tmp/{{ ambiance }}/{{ seed }}DEFAULT.j2"
    regexp: "{{ item.regexp1 }}"
    replace: "{{ item.replace }}"
  with_items: 
    - { regexp1: '^DBHOST.*$', replace: 'DBHOST = {% raw %}{{ databasehost }}{% endraw %}' }
    - { regexp1: '^GLOBALHOST.*$', replace: 'GLOBALHOST = {% raw %}{{ global_hostname }}{% endraw %}' }
```

I expect the following result:

```
DBHOST = {{ satabasehost }}
GLOBALHOST = {{ global_hostname }}
```

Any suggestions/ideas?

Answer (score 105):

`{% raw %}{{ databasehost }}{% endraw %}` should work.

You can also use `{{ '{{ databasehost }}' }}` as an alternative.

Comment: The OP explicitly states this didn't work for them.

Answer (score 7):

Just to avoid confusion:

With

- `ansible [core 2.14.0]`
- `jinja version = 3.1.2`

**all options are valid** from the [answer suggested by @blhsing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55464045/1622937), as well as, the [answer by @DustWolf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75098765/1622937).

Here is a toy example that demonstrates both the use of the approaches recommended in the official [jinja docs](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#escaping) and the use of ansible's [`!unsafe`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_advanced_syntax.html#unsafe-or-raw-strings) data type:

Consider the file `test.j2`:

```
DBHOST blabla
GLOBALHOST blablu
OTHERHOST blabli
```

and the `play.yml`:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  
  tasks:
    - name: test
      local_action:
        module: replace
        path: "{{ playbook_dir}}/test.j2"
        regexp: "{{ item.regexp1 }}"
        replace: "{{ item.replace }}"
      with_items:
        - { regexp1: '^DBHOST.*$', replace: 'DBHOST = {{ "{{ databasehost }}" }}' }
        - { regexp1: '^GLOBALHOST.*$', replace: 'GLOBALHOST = {% raw %}{{ global_hostname }}{% endraw %}' }
        - { regexp1: '^OTHERHOST.*$', replace: !unsafe 'OTHERHOST = {{ other_hostname }}' }
```

we end up with a modified `test.j2`:

```
DBHOST = {{ databasehost }}
GLOBALHOST = {{ global_hostname }}
OTHERHOST = {{ other_hostname }}
```

---

So the fact that the `{% raw %}...{% endraw %}` block did not work for the OP is **not** because that would not be a valid approach!
It is likely due to some particularity of the content of the file in which the replace is done, but that is just a guess.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `{% raw %}...{% endraw %}` does not work when the jinja2 syntax is invalid, for example when you are trying to output RADIUS configuration which contains `{%` but isn't actually jinja2 syntax. In that case, only the `!unsafe` option works.

Answer (score 3):

If you are doing this in Ansible (I realise the title only says jinja2), you can prepend `!unsafe` to the string. Example:

```yaml
local_action:
    module: replace
    path: "/tmp/{{ ambiance }}/{{ seed }}DEFAULT.j2"
    regexp: "{{ item.regexp1 }}"
    replace: "{{ item.replace }}"
  with_items: 
    - { regexp1: '^DBHOST.*$', replace: !unsafe 'DBHOST = {{ databasehost }}' }
    - { regexp1: '^GLOBALHOST.*$', replace: !unsafe 'GLOBALHOST = {{ global_hostname }}' }
```

This will cause all jinja2 syntax to be ignored.

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65295792/2897386